# How to add a variable from Json extractor into an array in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, json-extract

I'm new here and also a beginner on JMeter and maybe this was already answered in an old post that I didn't find, sorry if this is the case.

I had this Post request I need to send with all these IDs that vary according to the account
[Post Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5UHG.jpg)
In order to get all of the IDs, I used the JSon extractor to put then into a variable
[JSon extractor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoMDP.jpg), then I got all the FieldIDs that I need.
[ID extracted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYvf6.jpg)

But now how can I add this variable inside the request? I tried something like `{"ids":"${fieldId}","includeBoundary":true}` but it didn't work. How can I use this?
Please see: [HTTP Request parameter dialog example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHMW4.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem in a so easy way(damn it)!!!!

On the Json extractor I just marked the option ["Computer concatenation var (suffix_ALL)"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SL6Q.jpg) then on the debbuger I got [all IDs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSEoI.jpg) I needed in only one line and finally on my request I just add on the body data the line `{"ids": [${fieldId_ALL}],"includeBoundary":true}` and bingo it worked like a charm!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to extract the **whole response**, save it into a JMeter Variable and send it back to another endpoint - the easiest way is using [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter) providing empty left and right boundaries

[image]

If you need more complex transformations - take a look at [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)

Comment: I saw your post https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter and my problem is like In the first example you gave:
firstName_1=John
firstName_2=Anna
firstName_3=Peter
firstName_matchNr=3
How can you pass all these names at once in a body data? this is kind of my problem, I'm getting some field_IDs that is random because it dapends the account I'm using. 
fieldId_1=32664922
fieldId_2=32532081
fieldId_3=32532082
fieldId_matchNr=3
But how can I pass all of them in a simple way knowing that the number of ids is different depending on the user I'm logged?

Comment: this works, but how can I ignore the quotation marks in the form of my token "token